# Python Maze Solving - What architecture to use?

Tags: python, recursion, maze

I am fairly new to python and am trying to build a maze solver. I have already constructed an algorithm that can navigate a single route and print it's route (N/E/S/W), but I want to move this onto multiple routes. What kind of architecture should I use to handle multiple routes?

I was thinking of using classes and subclasses to model the different routes, so that subclasses inherit their 'stubs', but now I wonder if this might be overcomplicating it a bit. I have seen posts about recursion but have no idea where to start with something like that.

Does anyone have any suggestions? My code is below for single route if anyone is interested:

```
# =============================================================================
#  MAZE
# =============================================================================
# Edit this grid to change the maze. Codes are:

# 0 = Walkable
# 1 = Wall
# 2 = Start
# 3 = Finish

maze = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]


# =============================================================================
#  CLASSES AND METHODS
# =============================================================================


# Class which will hold all the routes
class Route():
    used = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.directions = []
        self.tracks = []
        self.status = 'Pending'


# Class which stores position of 'marker' and 'start' in maze
class Pos():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.coords = []    # Coordinates updated UPDATE_POS method
        self.N = []
        self.E = []
        self.S = []
        self.W = []

        self.update_pos(x, y)

    # When called, it updates values manually
    def update_pos(self, x, y):
        self.coords = [x, y]    # Coordinates updated from x and y
        self.N = [x, y-1, 'N']       # Directions define adjacents
        self.E = [x+1, y, 'E']
        self.S = [x, y+1, 'S']
        self.W = [x-1, y, 'W']

    # Find start of maze and set position
    def find_start(self, maze):

        for row in maze:
            if 2 not in row:
                continue
            if 2 in row:
                self.y = maze.index(row)
                self.x = maze[maze.index(row)].index(2)
                self.update_pos(self.x, self.y)

    # Check if the index is within the maze
    def valid_space(self, maze, index):        # index in the form [x,y]
        size = len(maze)

        if index[0] < size and index[1] < size:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    # Looks for walkable spaces and moves the position to that space
    def look_around(self, maze):

        directions = [self.N, self.E, self.S, self.W]

        for direction in directions:
            # Eliminate invalid moves, used or outside maze
            if self.valid_space(maze, direction):
                if direction[0:2] in Route.used:
                    continue
                # Look for walkable space
                if maze[direction[1]][direction[0]] == 0:
                    self.x = direction[0]
                    self.y = direction[1]
                    self.update_pos(self.x, self.y)
                    route1.directions.append(direction[2])
                    Route.used.append(self.coords)
                    break
                # Look for finish
                if maze[direction[1]][direction[0]] == 3:
                    self.x = direction[0]
                    self.y = direction[1]
                    self.update_pos(self.x, self.y)
                    route1.directions.append(direction[2])
                    Route.used.append(self.coords)
                    route1.status = 'Finished'
            else:
                continue


# =============================================================================
#  MAIN
# =============================================================================


# Initialise position and route
position = Pos(0, 0)
start_pos = Pos(0, 0)
route1 = Route()


# Change position to start of maze and print
start_pos.find_start(maze)
position.find_start(maze)    # Set position to start

print('Solving...')
while route1.status != 'Finished':
    position.look_around(maze)

print('''The directions to the finish are: ''')
print(route1.directions)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Thanks.  Surprising that nobody (including me) noticed this before.

Comment: No that's the code I have so far, I just needed a suggestion on how to include multiple routes into this? (I formatted it like this if that's what you're wondering)

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need a data structure more complicated than a list for tracking paths in a maze. You'll probably want to use a list of lists for keeping track of the paths that you've found.

As you develop your solution, consider how you can keep track of where you've been already.

Comment: Do you just have an algorithm that just takes random routes and then marks them done then? Does it recognise the index of the array as already visited?

Comment: Nope, you just need to be careful in your tracking of position while searching, and whenever you encounter the goal make a copy of the path. You may want to look at depth-first searches vs breadth-first searching.